# Передача структуры через сокеты TCP/IP

Tags: c, tcp-ip, linux

Как передать с сервера клиенту значение переменной типа структура? В send нужно ее преобразовать к типу char*. Как сделать это средствами языка СИ?

Comment: Гугл много чего говорит. Например http://s11n.net/c11n/, http://tpl.sourceforge.net/ и ещё много умных слов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе Вы можете написать

```
send(sock, &my_struct, sizeof(my_struct), 0);
```

и принять данные

```
recv (sock,&my_struct, sizeof(my_struct), 0);
```

но, тут полно подводных камней.

Comment: Попробовал передать. Собственно корректно ни одно поле не передалось. Какими способами можно обойти эти камни?

Comment: У Вас что структуры разные ?  

Структура это область памяти, поля в ней подряд (ну, может быть со сдвигом на выравнивание), важен порядок и тип, а не имя. Вообще, лучше описать структуру в одном .h и включить его (.h) в клиент и сервер. Еще компьютеры д.б. с одинаковой разрядностью и порядком байт. 

Вы примерчик приведите, что не работает. После send/recv печатайте количество переданных байт.

А скорее всего у Вас какая-то ошибка в прикладном протоколе обмена (рассогласованы передача и прием).

Comment: @carapuz А описание структуры можно посмотреть? Хотя в любом случае "ни одно поле" -- результат фантастический. Возможно ваш пёс был закопан в другом месте.

Answer (score 3):

Можно, как предложил [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp). Но для большей совместимости и надежности лучше передавать последовательно значения полей, притом зафиксировать их размер.

А еще лучше передавать в совершенно платформонезависимом виде, вроде форматов XML или JSON

Comment: Только вот разбирать это... (особенно XML). Лучше передавать в символьном виде значения полей в строках. sprintf(),fputs()/fgets(), sscanf(); Там же (в строках особо отформатированных) можно гнать информацию по синхронизации, управлению и т.п.